# Windows 7 Where are the icons of the Message Box stored [.DLL]

Tags: c#, windows

Does anyone know where the MessageBox symbols from windows are stored (Error icon, Exclamation Icon...). I think they are in a .dll file!

Comment: There are `ICON` resources in `user32.dll` where `MessageBox` resides. But that is actually implementation dependent.

Comment: @TheFlash The only supported way to use these icons without breaking the license is to use `LoadIcon` or similar. Don't extract the icons from the DLL because that breaks the license.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [System.Drawing.SystemIcons class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemicons.aspx) to access the stock icons used in Windows.  It includes the icons that are used in MessageBox.

Technically you can use File + Open + File in Visual Studio and navigate to c:\windows\system32\user32.dll to get these icons as well.  That is however not legal.  Nor is there any guarantee that they'll look the same on a later version of Windows, they probably won't.  Use SystemIcons instead.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are in a DLL file, but you're not supposed to load them directly from there. If you need them at runtime, use `LoadIcon(IDI_EXCLAMATION)`, for example.

If you need them at design time, then look in the [Visual Studio Image Library](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35825).

Comment: Thank you ! I needed them at design time :)

Comment: If you need them at designtime, then you can still use `LoadIcon(IDI_EXCLAMATION)`

Comment: Can you give me an Example how to use LoadIcon in C#?